# how to access the web ip camera on the opentopia?

Tags: camera, video-streaming

I am viewing an ip camera from http://www.opentopia.com/webcam/16031, I have two questions
1. how it is streaming through the web page on the opentopia website,

2. is it possible to access and record the stream of that camera through ffmpeg or some other software ?

Answer (score 0):

This site uses an mjpeg, stream. any program that can do http requests can download it.